# How to add children where empty in nested object?

Tags: php

I have a **multidimensional** array with over 200 nested objects which some have children and some don't.
I'm trying to add empty children to where `leaf: false` and `children` don't exist.

```
   [{
        "id": "GRP-25",
        "text": "Name 1",
        "leaf": false,
        "children": [{
            "id": "APP-222",
            "text": "Another name",
            "leaf": true
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "GRP-25",
        "text": "Name 2",
        "leaf": false,
        "children": [] // <- missing, need to add empty children
    }
]



function addEmptyChildren(array &$data)
{
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) 
    {
        // recursive call 
        if (is_array($v)) {
            addEmptyChildren($data[$k]);
            continue;
        }

        if ($data['leaf'] === false && !property_exists('children', $k)) {
            $data['children'] = [];
        }
    }
}

addEmptyChildren($result);
```

Comment: `$data['children'] = [];` => `$data['children'] = [(object)[]];`? idk wha you mean by "empty children"

Comment: "empty children" I mean to add `"children": [] ` to the object. Because currently is missing if no children assigned.

Comment: If you have an array, why are you showing us invalid JSON

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I fixed the invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see the problem. Based on `is_array()`, `$data['leaf']`, etc., it looks like the function is meant to deal with an array of arrays, probably from `json_decode($json, true)`, rather than an array of objects. If that's the case, then `property_exists` is not the right way to check for children.

Instead of this:

```
if ($data['leaf'] === false && !property_exists('children', $k)) {
```

use `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` instead.

```
if ($data['leaf'] === false && !isset($data['children'])) {
```

Comment: is assigning `$data['children'] = [(object)[]];` the correct way to do it because it's not adding `"children": []` to the JSON output.

Comment: `$data['children'] = [];` works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A lot more going on in your loop than appears to be necessary.

```
$str = '[{
    "id": "GRP-25",
    "text": "Name 1",
    "leaf": false,
    "children": [{
        "id": "APP-222",
        "text": "Another name",
        "leaf": true
    }]
},
{
    "id": "GRP-25",
    "text": "Name 2",
    "leaf": false
}
]';
$result = json_decode($str);
if (json_last_error() !== 0){echo json_last_error_msg();}
#print_r($result);

function addEmptyChildren(array &$data)
{
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {

        if ($v->leaf === false && !isset($v->children)) {
            $v->children = [];
        }
    }
}

addEmptyChildren($result);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

RESULT

```
[
    {
        "id": "GRP-25",
        "text": "Name 1",
        "leaf": false,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "APP-222",
                "text": "Another name",
                "leaf": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "GRP-25",
        "text": "Name 2",
        "leaf": false,
        "children": []
    }
]
```